# JSON Decode Error for fetching huge Data from SQL Server - Python

Tags: php, json, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to fetch data from SQL server using `requests` module from Python by querying a `php` file, and here's my code:

```
import requests

# api-endpoint
URL = "https://*******.co.in/******/queryRandom.php"

# location given here
token= '******************'

    query2= 'SELECT userId,dateTime FROM storeActivity WHERE dateTime >= "2018-07-01"'

    # defining a params dict for the parameters to be sent to the API
    PARAMS = {'token':token, 'query':query2}

    # sending get request and saving the response as response object
    r2 = requests.post(url = URL, data = PARAMS)

    data2=r2.json()
    df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)
    df2=df2.ix[df2['userId']!=1]
    df2=df2.ix[df2['userId']!=0]
    df2.head(1)
```

The shape of the dataframe is `(573315, 2)`. But I want it for last 3 months so I'm changing the `query2` to `query2= 'SELECT userId,dateTime FROM storeActivity WHERE dateTime >= "2018-05-01"'`, but unfortunately I'm getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-69c7bfbb6dca> in <module>()
      7 r2 = requests.post(url = URL, data = PARAMS)
      8 
----> 9 data2=r2.json()
     10 df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

When  I downloaded offline by exporting `csv` from the SQL server I was able  to load it into my notebook. It has a shape of `(1052365,2)`. So is this error occurring because of the size of data? Or do I need to make any changes in my code or in that `queryRandom.php` file?

Comment: Can you print last few characters in the data2 string by `print(r2.text[:-100])` and take a look is really data missing at the end?

Comment: why did u delete your answer dude? Someone could've helped us. Maybe you're missing something small.
Anyway I'm getting an `<html>` coded file altogether

Comment: Because it is obvious that problem is not from python requests. If you get `html` response by `.text()`, it means you need to check your `php` sides code.